# How to assign a std::string back to a std::vector<char>.data() passed as a void* pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the below code, which passes an input string as a source `void*` to function `filter()` along with a `vector<char>` as a destination `void*`.

How can it assign the processed string back to the destination `void*` so that it can be passed back to `main()`?

```
size_t filter(void* destination, const void* source, size_t source_size)
{
    std::string source_string(static_cast<const char*>(source));

    std::string destination_string;

    // Do some processing on destination_string

    // HAS NO EFFECT ????????????????????
    destination = (&destination_string);

    return destination_string.size();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> buffer;
    buffer.reserve(100);
    auto return_size = filter(buffer.data(), "Appollo", 7);

    std::string str(buffer.begin(), buffer.begin()+return_size);
    std::cout << str.c_str();
}
```

P.S. This is a problem from an online coding challenge.

Comment: Why don't you return the `std:: string`?

Comment: What do you think happen with the variable `destination_string` once the function returns? When the variable goes out of scope, and the life-time of the object ends and it's destructed? Although that's not currently a problem as you pass the pointer *by value*.

Comment: Why are you doing *any* of this? And what makes you think that any of it is well defined behavior?

Comment: You can use `std::copy` but why are you passing `void*` rather than `char*`? And writing to the reserve area of a vector is hardly good/safe practice.

Comment: Related, the only way to get the non-const pointer for writing to [some] container's internal buffer is taking the address of element `0`. That is, `std::vector<char> data(<some size>); char* ptr = &data[0]`. But there are easier/better ways to do what you want to do.

Comment: @jww, [First overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data). If you'd prefer to make that more general, use `std::data`.

Comment: @jww non-const `data()` methods were added to some containers in C++11 (like `vector`), and to others in C++17. `std::data()` was added in C++17.

Comment: This is a problem from an online coding challenge

Answer (score 1):

The statement `destination = (&destination_string)` simply assigns the memory address of a local `std::string` variable to a pointer that is also local to the function. It is not copying the character data into the caller's buffer at all.

Try something more like this instead:

```
size_t filter(void* destination, size_t destination_size, const void* source, size_t source_size)
{
    std::string source_string(static_cast<const char*>(source), source_size);

    std::string destination_string;
    // Do some processing on destination_string

    auto size = std::min(destination_string.size(), destination_size);
    std::copy_n(destination_string.begin(), size, static_cast<char*>(destination));

    return size;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<char> buffer;
    buffer.resize(100);
    auto return_size = filter(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), "Appollo", 7);

    std::string str(buffer.data(), return_size);
    std::cout << str;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It does exactly what the OP is asking for